# CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-analytics, pycrypto

I'm trying to run an application for AppEngine with python where I'm import the example module to get data from Google Analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py but when I run the server with dev_appserver.py and go to localhost:8080/ I recive  an 505 error with his error in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ingdavid/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/ingdavid/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/ingdavid/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/ingdavid/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/ingdavid/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/ingdavid/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/repositorios/PYTHON/dashboard/app.py", line 248, in get
    print analyticsH.main()
  File "/var/www/repositorios/PYTHON/dashboard/analyticsH.py", line 111, in main
    service_account_email)
  File "/var/www/repositorios/PYTHON/dashboard/analyticsH.py", line 35, in get_service
    scope=scope)
  File "/var/www/repositorios/PYTHON/dashboard/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/repositorios/PYTHON/dashboard/oauth2client/client.py", line 1503, in __init__   _RequireCryptoOrDie()
  File "/var/www/repositorios/PYTHON/dashboard/oauth2client/client.py", line 1457, in _RequireCryptoOrDie
    raise CryptoUnavailableError('No crypto library available')
CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available
```

I've searched and all that I've found is install openssl or install python-crypto or update python-dev, I doing everything but not works.

Thank you.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en include pycrypto in your yaml file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already do this but no works :(

Comment: @DavidLinares, please don't ask questions in comments -- rather edit your question to be complete or close this one and open another.

Comment: David, could you copy your yaml in the question, and make sure you get the SAME error after you include it in your yaml?